# How to get BorderLayout south width and height?

Tags: java, swing, border, layout-manager

How do I get `BorderLayout.SOUTH`'s width and height?

I want to get the height and width of the layout's center and south and etc. When I write `getWidth()`and `getHeight()`, it returns only the center's width and height.

Comment: Be ready for plenty of downvotes

Comment: Learn to use the javadocs: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/

Comment: It's not so bad ever since I edited it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, LayoutManagers don't have heights and widths. The whole point of LayoutManagers are to give you layout control, not size control. Components have a size. Your call to `getHeight()` and `getWidth()` (if not called from another component), is just giving you the width and height of the wrapping container, not the BorderLayout

So if your class is like this

```
public class Something extends JPanel {

}
```

you call to `getHeight()` and `getWidth()` would give you the height and width of the `Something` panel